# C: How to convert a pointer (array element) to int?

Tags: c, string, pointers, fgets

I'm trying to code using `fgets` a program that would get an number input from user and then divide it by 10000000. And I know that a string element `(of type 'int *')` couldn't be divided by an `int` type.

```
int count;
int input[MAXLEN];

for ( count = 1; count <= 20; count++ ) {
      while (( fgets ( input[count], MAXLEN, stdin)) != 0 ) {
        if ( (input[count] / 10000000) != 20 ) {
            /* Some code dealing with this condition */
        }
      }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The compiler gives me this error:

```
program.c:10:24: error: invalid operands to binary / (have int * and int)
```

If the input must be of type `char *` why does my compiler say `int *`?

I know that `input[count]`cannot be divided since it is a pointer. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, or at least how to convert the input from `fgets` to an `int`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are your types? Try to quote a complete program. And please give the errors your compiler tells you: I imagine, it's good starting point ;-)

Comment: Hot parts of your code aren't there (what "input" is?) but: fgets reads STRINGS, int* is not a string (=an array of characters) but an array of integers (even if user inputs a number...)

Comment: Okay I've edited it, giving the compiler error message and the initialization of the variables. @Adriano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` should not be an `int *`, but rather a `char *`. This will return a C-string, which is a series of characters terminated by null. If you use`atoi()`, you will be able to get the contents of that string interpreted as an integer.

Comment: +1 but, it should be char** (instead of char*) because it's used inside a loop (even if I'm not sure about what he's really trying to do)

Comment: True. When I said `input`, what I was thinking was `input[count]`.

Comment: And then you need to remember that the memory fgets reads into must already be allocated ...